# Regex to extract all pair of words and their respectively 3 words after and 3 words before in Python

Tags: python, regex

Regex to extract all pair of words and their respectively 3 words after and 3 words before

This is my regex:

```
((?:[\S,]+\s+){0,3})((?:[\S,]+\s*){0,3})
```

This is the text:

```
Quadriband - UMTS - HSDPA - HSUPA - LTE - Wi-Fi Fotocamera da 8 Megapixel - Lettore MP3 Sistema Operativo iOS8 - GPS integrato
```

I only get these results:

```
Quadriband - UMTS  - HSDPA - 
HSUPA - LTE  - Wi-Fi Fotocamera 
da 8 Megapixel  - Lettore MP3 
Sistema Operativo iOS8  - GPS integrato
```

But I want all combination especially the `- Wi-Fi Fotocamera - da 8 Megapixel`

How can I edit my regex to catch all possible 3 (also 0, 1 or 2 will be fine) words before and 3 (also 0, 1 or 2 will be fine) words after a space..

https://regex101.com/r/mP9lT9/1

Comment: actually you want every 6 consecutive words?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: All possible 3 (also 0, 1 or 2 will be fine) words before and 3 (also 0, 1 or 2 will be fine) words after a space...

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you want every 6 consecutive none whitespace sub string.So you don't need regex for this task you can use `itertools.islice` within a list comprehension :

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> 
>>> [' '.join(islice(li,i,i+6)) for i in range(len(li))]
['Quadriband - UMTS - HSDPA -', '- UMTS - HSDPA - HSUPA', 'UMTS - HSDPA - HSUPA -', '- HSDPA - HSUPA - LTE', 'HSDPA - HSUPA - LTE -', '- HSUPA - LTE - Wi-Fi', 'HSUPA - LTE - Wi-Fi Fotocamera', '- LTE - Wi-Fi Fotocamera da', 'LTE - Wi-Fi Fotocamera da 8', '- Wi-Fi Fotocamera da 8 Megapixel', 'Wi-Fi Fotocamera da 8 Megapixel -', 'Fotocamera da 8 Megapixel - Lettore', 'da 8 Megapixel - Lettore MP3', '8 Megapixel - Lettore MP3 Sistema', 'Megapixel - Lettore MP3 Sistema Operativo', '- Lettore MP3 Sistema Operativo iOS8', 'Lettore MP3 Sistema Operativo iOS8 -', 'MP3 Sistema Operativo iOS8 - GPS', 'Sistema Operativo iOS8 - GPS integrato', 'Operativo iOS8 - GPS integrato', 'iOS8 - GPS integrato', '- GPS integrato', 'GPS integrato', 'integrato']
```

Also if you have a special condition for your words you can find the words with passing a specific regex to `re.findall` and use it as `s.split`.